# Twilio Speech Recognition - twiml.say not working when dialing to IVR

Tags: twilio

I'm trying out speech recognition and can't figure out why the twiml.say command is not working when dialing to an IVR system

the webhook

```
  exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    twiml.gather({
      input: 'speech',
      timeout: 20,
      action: '/ivr-eng'

    });
    callback(null, twiml);
 };
```

/ivr-eng:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  const speechCommand = event.SpeechResult.toLowerCase();

  twiml.say(speechCommand);

  if(speechCommand == "please enter number.")
  {

    twiml.say('Hi There');
    console.log('Hi There');

  }

  console.log(speechCommand);
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

The console.log inside the if statement and outside gets executed and i can see the same in the logs, however both the twiml.say statements is not executed

I debug by recording the call and listening into it.

Note: When I call the twilio number from my personal mobile, the twiml.say works and i can hear the same from the recordings.

Comment: Is the timeout of 20 seconds too long for the IVR that you're dialling to? I'd perhaps try playing with shorter timeouts.

Comment: I did with 10 seconds and then down to 3 seconds, it still does not work. And all the times, the recordings last only 13 seconds (ringing and IVR menu 'please enter number')

Comment: That's weird and I have no explanation I'm afraid. I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and send them a call SID in which this happened. They can then investigate properly.

Comment: Thanks philnash, opened a new twilio support request to sort this issue